# Whether the application will be live during the time of POD deployment in AKS?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops

Whether the application will be live (In transaction) during the time of POD deployment in AKS?

While we are performing the POD deployment, whether the application transactions will go through (or) get error out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Deployment system does a rolling update. New pods are created with the new template and once Ready they are added to the service load balancer, and then old ones are removed and terminated.

Comment: What exactly happens to the front end application (transaction) which is consuming the microservice? What will happen to that transaction? Whether it will get aborted or continue with older deployment service?

Comment: If you write your application correctly so that it doesn't exit until active requests are done, then they complete normally. There is a grace period during pod termination between when a pod is removed from the load balancer and when it is forcibly killed. You get a SIGTERM first, and most web servers treat that as a gentle shutdown command.

Comment: I am from DevOps .. I will have to manage the source code for  build & deployment life cycle. In my understanding, that specific transaction might live in the buffer and will continue to handle as per the existing code. In other words, we can manage the build & deployment without the down time. (Only for Microservice deployment) Please correct me, if i am wrong.

Comment: You will have to check each application or get another team to do so. But this is not specific to Kubernetes, it's just the usual implementation of rolling updates for zero downtime changes. If your service supports a "finish work and then exit" command or signal then you can use that.